# How do I coerce str to correct type for pygame.mixer (Python)?

Tags: python, linux, pygame

I have some python code that works in windows with the following code:

```
winsound.PlaySound(a_sound, winsound.SND_MEMORY)
```

Of course, in linux this doesn't work. I've tried the following (using docs from http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html as a guide):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(a_sound)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
sound.play()
while pygame.mixer.get_busy():
    clock.tick(30)
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str
```

`a_sound` is not the name of a file, rather it is a `<type 'str'>` containing uncompressed PCM data (with correct RIFF.WAV header)

How do I use `pygame.mixer` to correctly render the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sound` expects a file name or a file-like object. You can create the latter from a string using `StringIO`:

```
import cStringIO
...
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(cStringIO.StringIO(a_sound))
```

Comment: @Octopus Also, according to [the documentation], you're supposed to be able to pass a [`buffer` object](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#buffer), i.e. `buffer(a_sound)`, but that didn't work for me when I tested it — there was no exception, but the sound was incorrect. But `cStringIO` is also a very efficient solution.

Comment: cStringIO.StringIO(a_sound) works, but it plays back too quickly buffer(a_sound) also works and plays back even more quickly. Ive even tried to set sound parameters explicitly with pygame.mixer.init(48000,16,1,2048), but theres no difference. the parameters seem to be ignored.

Comment: @Octopus Unfortunately I cannot help you with that, as I have never used pygame - except today, to test the code I posted in the answer. FWIW, it played a OGG song flawlessly for me (under Linux).